# A problem of inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $a_1, a_2, a_3$; $b_1, b_2, b_3$; $c_1, c_2, c_3$; $d_1, d_2, d_3$ be all real numbers.

We need to show that 
$$\begin{align}(a_1b_1c_1d_1 + a_2b_2c_2d_2 &+ a_3b_3c_3d_3)^4\\ &\leq (a_1^4+a_2^4+a_3^4)(b_1^4+b_2^4+b_3^4)(c_1^4+c_2^4+c_3^4)(d_1^4+d_2^4+d_3^4)\end{align}$$

> I have used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality on $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(A_1,A_2,A_3)$ where $A_i=b_ic_id_i$ and get the following 
>   $$(a_1A_1+a_2A_2+a_3A_3)< (a_1^2+a_3^2+a_3^2)^{1/2}(A_1^2+A_3^2+A_3^2)^{1/2}$$ Next my aim was to assume $B_i=c_id_i$ and go forward. But this does not help and fails therefore.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Comment: A warm welcome from me too. You should add what you tried to the question post, rather than the comment section. Also, if your trying to respond specifically to @5xum , use the @ nameoftheuser, this way he gets notified you have replied.

Comment: OK @ The Artist

Comment: @user1942348 , ummm dont keep a space between @ and the name of the user next time :)

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz on $(a_i)$ and $(A_i)$ does not yield what you wrote.

Comment: Not entirely sure why your post was voted closed, but here is a hint on how to use CS twice to prove that - $(a_1^4+a_2^4+a_3^4)(b_1^4+b_2^4+b_3^4)(c_1^4+c_2^4+c_3^4)(d_1^4+d_2^4+d_3^4) \ge (a_1^2b_1^2+...)^2(c_1^2d_1^2+...)^2 \ge (a_1b_1c_1d_1+...)^4$

Comment: Now, due to corrections by others, Cauchy-Schwarz on $(a_i)$ and $(A_i)$ does yield what is written.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is an application of the [Hölder's Inequality](https://brilliant.org/wiki/holders-inequality/).

More specifically,

$$(a_1^4 + a_2^4 + a_3^4)^\frac{1}{4}\cdots(d_1^4 + d_2^4 + d_3^4)^\frac{1}{4} \ge \left[ a_1^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}b_1^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}c_1^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}d_1^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)} + \cdots + a_4^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}b_4^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}c_4^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}d_4^{\left(4 \cdot \frac{1}{4}\right)}\right]$$

$$\iff (a_1^4 + a_2^4 + a_3^4)\cdots(d_1^4 + d_2^4 + d_3^4) \ge (a_1b_1c_1d_1 + \cdots + a_4b_4c_4d_4)^4$$

Comment: Do you mean $a_4=b_4=c_4=d_4=0$?

Comment: No, I'm not sure how you got that from.

Comment: See, on the LHS, you don't have $a_4,b_4,c_4,d_4$, but on the RHS you do. Why?